# Inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{18}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}+\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}+\frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{18}$$

This inequality is strengthening of the following Vasile Cirtoaje's one, which he  created in 2005.

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive numbers. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{a^3}{2a^2+b^2}+\frac{b^3}{2b^2+c^2}+\frac{c^3}{2c^2+a^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{3}.$$

My proof of this inequality you can see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h22937p427220

But this way does not help for the starting inequality.

A big problem we have around the point $(a,b,c)=(0.785, 1.25, 1.861)$ because the difference between the LHS and the RHS in this point is  $0.0000158...$.

I tried also to use Cauchy-Schwarz, but without success.

Also, I think the BW (see here https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/buffalo-way/info I tryed!) does not help.

Comment: Is the function $f : (a,b,c) \rightarrow \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{6a^3}{13a^2+5b^2} $ concave? Also, C-S = "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality"? Avoid this kind of unconventional abbreviation, please.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775572/olympiad-inequality-sum-cyc-fracx48x35y3-geqslant-fracxyz13

Comment: @David Quinn my inequality is much harder. BW does not help here.

Comment: Since this inequality lacks convexity and is not stable under slight changes to its coefficients $(5,13)$, I don't expect there to be a "nice" proof.



A computer algebra system reduces this problem to a system of polynomial equations and then solves this system by computing a Gröbner basis and numerically approximating the roots of polynomials with very high degrees.



What kind of proof are you looking for?

Comment: @cafaxo In my life I proved many inequalities by hand, which very hard to prove even with  computer. I am ready to show an example. Hence, I know, that I ask.

Comment: Hello Michael Rozenberg , I can reduce your problem in a problem with one variable . For it I use the software SageMath .All the proof need basic Tools (Gröbner basis is useless ) . I will post it in an another comment . The only matter is that the proof is ugly ...Have a good day.

Comment: @max8128 Thank you for your interest. I believe that there is a nice proof for this inequality.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Hi! I'm curious, I ask respectfully, interested in what are you doing. Since I never encountered problems such as this in my math education. What's the deal with inequalities? How did you came up with that problem, is it a conjecture of yours? Does this came up of a sub-problem while trying to solve another problem? You seem to be an expert in inequalities from your profile.

Comment: @Santropedro There is the following known inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. I think, it's just interesting, for which maximal value of $k$ the following inequality is still true. $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{ka^2+b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{k+1}$.

Comment: @Santropedro The value $\,k=2.6\,$ in the OP is pretty sharp. I found that $k=2.603279$ is already beyond: Then Michael's given
$(0.785, 1.25, 1.861)$ violates the ineq..

Comment: Further result obtained via random-based simulation: 
$(0.785, 1.2535, 1.873)$ doesn't satisfy the inequality if $\,k=2.603262\,$. Below that $k$-value I didn't detect a violation.

Comment: @Hanno I don't understand why do you reply that to me, maybe you are directing to others? I don't understand what you are trying to convey me.

Comment: @Santropedro My numerical output refers to Michael R.'s last comment which is replying to yours. So I thought this might be interesting for you as well, hence the alert. (And Michael R. as OP is alerted anyway.) Beyond the existence of a 'nice proof' (for which math.SE is longing) the quest for the maximal $k$-value such that the ineq still holds true $\forall\, a,b,c>0\,$ is a quite interesting follow-up.

Comment: @Hanno Ah ok thanks.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg . Your inequality is an application of the [Levinson's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levinson%27s_inequality).

Comment: @max8128 I don't think so.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg what do you think about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2293748/a-strong-inequality-from-michael-rozenberg)?

Comment: @max8128 I don't like it. I am sorry.

Comment: The general problem is here : https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h20513p815736

Comment: @knm I knew about existing of this topic. Now we need to prove it!

Comment: @Vincent I drew the graph of $f(a,b,1)$ with Mathcad and it is not concave.

Comment: @knm Indeed, it is always better to cite one's sources, if only for context.

Comment: Dear @Did I created the starting inequality  by myself, when solved the following problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h22937p427220 Easy to understand that it was before the Ji Chen's generalization. By the way, the Ji Chen's problem is open, but my problem we'll can solve, I hope.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Do you believe me if I say we can use Jensen's inequality on this problem ?

Comment: I don't believe that it's possible

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If you don' believe that we cannot use convexity and Karamata's inequality see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563335/prove-or-disprove-this-statement).It's not a complete proof but it's the first time I see Karamata's inequality and Buffalo's way together .Teach this to your pupils =)

Comment: Do you want to avoid using Lagrange multipliers? It wouldn't be so bad with just three variables.

Comment: @Maxim Gilula No. If it goes to solution by hand, why no.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I tried for a few hours, but the best I could do by hand was reduce this problem to finding roots of a fourth degree polynomial. So unless you know the quartic formula, this idea might be useless :(

Comment: Can [this form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927871/inequality-proof-fracaa2-b213a25b2-fracbb2-c213b25c2?noredirect=1&lq=1) of the problem be solved using determinants?

Answer (score 10):

@Maxim Gilula asked a good question: What is the point of presenting a solution via computer?

Let me address it from two aspects.

First, from my experience (the problems from MSE, AoPS, academic research etc.), the inequalities with elegant solutions (e.g. by hand)
are usually those designed e.g. for contest. Except for the designed inequalities, the inequalities require usually the help of computer. 
Many inequalities in MSE, AoPS are open for many years without any solution by hand.

Second, although also with the help of computer, the solutions are different.

1) Some solutions e.g. Buffalo Way (BW) or Sum of Squares (SOS) provide step-by-step rigorous complete analytical solutions with detailed explanation. 
Moreover, these solutions are often not very long. Usually one or several A4 pages are enough to write down the step-by-step rigorous complete analytical solutions with detailed explanation.

2) In contrast, some solutions does not provided step-by-step solutions. For example, the step-by-step solutions are in Mathematica's innards,
and for some cases, Mathematica run several hours to output 'true' which means that the step-by-step solutions may be very, very long,
probably 10,000 A4 pages are required to write down the step-by-step solutions. 
Sometimes the method of Lagrange Multiplier works well, however, sometimes it results in very complicated equations which requires Mathematica etc.

3) Often, although the thinking process is very complicated and requires the help of computer, 
the solution is elementary and easy to check even by hand. For example, recently, I used computer to solve an inequality in AoPS to get the identity
$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - a^2b - b^2c - c^2a
= \frac{(a^2+b^2-2c^2)^2 + 3(a^2-b^2)^2
+ \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} 4(a+b)(c+a)(a-b)^2}{8(a+b+c)}$. In contrast, Mathematica only outputs 'true'. Which solution is better?

**EDIT**

Remark: Actually, the Buffalo Way works though the solution is ugly. I do not put it here. With computer, here is an SOS (Sum of Squares) solution:

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$.
We have
\begin{align*}
&\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2} + \frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2} + \frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2} - \frac{a+b+c}{18}\\
=\ & \frac{1}{18(13a^2+5b^2)(13b^2+5c^2)(13c^2+5a^2)}\\
&\quad \cdot \frac{1}{2223}\Big(cz_1^TA_1 z_1 + c(a-c)(b-c)z_2^TA_2z_2 + (b-c)z_3^TA_3z_3 + (a-c)z_4^TA_4z_4\Big)
\end{align*}
(Remark: $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are all positive definite. So the inequality is true.)
where
$$z_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c} {\left(a - c\right)}^2\, \left(b - c\right)\\ \left(a - c\right)\, {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c\, {\left(a - c\right)}^2\\ c\, \left(a - c\right)\, \left(b - c\right)\\ c\, {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c^2\, \left(b - c\right)\\ c^2\, \left(a - c\right) \end{array}\right),
\quad z_2 = \left(\begin{array}{c} {\left(a - c\right)}^2\\ \left(a - c\right)\, \left(b - c\right)\\ {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c\, \left(a - c\right)\\ c^2\\ c\, \left(b - c\right) \end{array}\right),
$$
$$z_3 = \left(\begin{array}{c} {\left(a - c\right)}^2\, \left(b - c\right)\\ \left(a - c\right)\, {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c\, {\left(a - c\right)}^2\\ c\, \left(a - c\right)\, \left(b - c\right)\\ c\, {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c^2\, \left(b - c\right)\\ c^2\, \left(a - c\right) \end{array}\right)
, \quad z_4 = \left(\begin{array}{c} {\left(a - c\right)}^2\, \left(b - c\right)\\ \left(a - c\right)\, {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c\, {\left(a - c\right)}^2\\ c\, \left(a - c\right)\, \left(b - c\right)\\ c\, {\left(b - c\right)}^2\\ c^2\, \left(b - c\right)\\ c^2\, \left(a - c\right) \end{array}\right),$$
and
$$A_1 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} 453245 & -100035 & 111397 & 113607 & -146718 & 24687 & 6498\\ -100035 & 166231 & -19773 & 24453 & -82004 & -11286 & 31356\\ 111397 & -19773 & 444600 & 86526 & -144261 & 13585 & -6669\\ 113607 & 24453 & 86526 & 760500 & -344736 & -126711 & 149188\\ -146718 & -82004 & -144261 & -344736 & 297882 & -26676 & -53352\\ 24687 & -11286 & 13585 & -126711 & -26676 & 160056 & -111150\\ 6498 & 31356 & -6669 & 149188 & -53352 & -111150 & 160056 \end{array}\right),
$$
$$A_2 = \left(\begin{array}{cccccc} 281580 & 33098 & -64467 & 40261 & 4275 & -24219\\ 33098 & 329004 & -124982 & 13572 & 20241 & -51129\\ -64467 & -124982 & 106704 & -51129 & -6840 & -30875\\ 40261 & 13572 & -51129 & 326610 & -8645 & -79794\\ 4275 & 20241 & -6840 & -8645 & 62244 & -46683\\ -24219 & -51129 & -30875 & -79794 & -46683 & 153216 \end{array}\right)
,$$
$$A_3 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} 258609 & -100035 & 102011 & 75582 & -56069 & -57798 & 126945\\ -100035 & 55575 & -37791 & -29393 & 2223 & 26923 & -26676\\ 102011 & -37791 & 589342 & 224757 & -195624 & -155376 & 313272\\ 75582 & -29393 & 224757 & 693576 & -279851 & -320283 & 535977\\ -56069 & 2223 & -195624 & -279851 & 200070 & 91143 & -306945\\ -57798 & 26923 & -155376 & -320283 & 91143 & 293436 & -435708\\ 126945 & -26676 & 313272 & 535977 & -306945 & -435708 & 1016158 \end{array}\right)
,$$
$$A_4 = \left(\begin{array}{ccccccc} 144495 & -57057 & 3705 & 24206 & -22230 & 2457 & 26923\\ -57057 & 55575 & 4199 & -15561 & -22724 & 13338 & -1989\\ 3705 & 4199 & 200070 & 18031 & -46449 & -9063 & 17784\\ 24206 & -15561 & 18031 & 351468 & -140049 & -6435 & -13509\\ -22230 & -22724 & -46449 & -140049 & 189202 & -117990 & -46449\\ 2457 & 13338 & -9063 & -6435 & -117990 & 177840 & -48659\\ 26923 & -1989 & 17784 & -13509 & -46449 & -48659 & 253422 \end{array}\right).
$$

Comment: If you are allowed to use a computer, there are 100 different solutions. What is the point of presenting a solution via computer? Might as well copy and paste wolfram alpha "minimize f(x,y,z)." This doesn't deserve 100 bounty -- no answer here does. Lagrange may be less work and can be actually done by hand if you somehow memorized how to solve quartic equations and doesn't involve a computer, or once you're at that step use a computer.

Comment: @MaximGilula Thank you for comments. Let me reply in the beginning of the solution because the comments are too long.

Comment: Thanks for your useful remarks!

Comment: @MaximGilula   Welcome to discuss. This inequality is waiting for elegant solutions (e.g. by hand) for many years.

Comment: I have found this link https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WitchofAgnesi.html . Where we recognize (the cartesian equation) an element of the LHS.So do you think there exists a geometric proof of this fact ?Thanks.

Comment: @The.old.boy  Interesting. You found that it has some geometric meaning.

Comment: @RiverLi How did you find those matrices?

Comment: @didgogns We used sostools+Matlab to find them.

Answer (score 3):

A bit algebra shows that the inequality is equivalent to
$$
5 \left(5 a^5 \left(13 b^2+5 c^2\right)+13 a^4 \left(5 b^3-13 b^2 c-5 b c^2-5 c^3\right)+a^3 \left(-65 b^4+144 b^2 c^2+65 c^4\right)+a^2 \left(25 b^5-65 b^4 c+144 b^3 c^2+144 b^2 c^3-169 b c^4+65 c^5\right)-13 a \left(13 b^4 c^2+5 b^2 c^4\right)+5 b^2 c^2 \left(13 b^3+13 b^2 c-13 b c^2+5 c^3\right)\right) \ge0
$$
The left hand side is a polynomial, so this can be solved by Cylindrical Algebra Decomposition -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_algebraic_decomposition

The following code in Mathematica does the job.

```
ex1 = a^3/(13 a^2 + 5 b^2) + b^3/(13 b^2 + 5 c^2) + c^3/(5 a^2 + 13 c^2) >= 1/18 (a + b + c);
ex2 = ex1[[1]] - ex1[[2]] // Together // Numerator // Simplify;
ex3 = ForAll[{a, b, c}, And @@ {a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0}, ex2 >= 0];
CylindricalDecomposition[ex3, {}]
```

Note this may take a few minutes to run.

Comment: It took no more than a second! `{0.508681, True}`

Comment: @youthdoo Computer or algorithm must have improved over the years!

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality is equivalent to :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{13}\sin(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{a}{b}))^2\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$$
Each side is divided by $b$, We get:
$$\frac{a}{13b} \sin(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{a}{b}))^2+\frac{1}{13}\sin(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{b}{c}))^2+\frac{c}{13b}\sin(\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{c}{a}))^2\geq \frac{1+\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}}{18}$$
Now we put $\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{a}{b}=x$, $\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{b}{c}=y$, $\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}\frac{c}{a}=z$, your inequality is equivalent to:
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}\frac{1}{13}\dfrac{(x)^3}{(x^2+1)}+\dfrac{1}{13}\dfrac{(y)^2}{(y^2+1)}+\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{5}}\dfrac{1}{13(y)}\dfrac{(z)^2}{(z^2+1)}$$$$\geq \dfrac{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}x+\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{5}}\dfrac{1}{y}}{18}$$
with the condition $xyz=(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}})^3$.

We study the following function:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}\frac{1}{13}\dfrac{(x)^3}{(x^2+1)}+\dfrac{1}{13}\dfrac{(y)^2}{(y^2+1)}+\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{5}}\dfrac{1}{13(y)}\dfrac{(z)^2}{(z^2+1)}-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}x+\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{5}}\dfrac{1}{y}}{18}$$
This function is easily differentiable and the minimum is for $x=\sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{77}}{17}-\frac{26}{17}}=\alpha$. So with the condition $xyz=(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}})^3$ becomes $yz=\frac{(\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}})^3}{\alpha}=\beta$. So we have this inequality just with $y$:
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}\frac{1}{13}\dfrac{(\alpha)^3}{(\alpha^2+1)}+\dfrac{1}{13}\dfrac{(y)^2}{(y^2+1)}+\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{5}}\dfrac{1}{13(y)}\dfrac{(\frac{\beta}{y})^2}{((\frac{\beta}{y})^2+1)}\geq\dfrac{1+\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{13}}\alpha+\sqrt{\dfrac{13}{5}}\dfrac{1}{y}}{18}$$
which is easily analyzable. Done!

Comment: Why the last inequality is true?

Comment: Wow you analyze rapidly (without irony).I check it with wolfram alpha but I will create a question for this I think .

Comment: We can check the starting inequality by WA without your previous work. But maybe WA is wrong (by the way, it happens sometimes!).

Comment: Are you agree with this fact $$sin(arctan(x))^2=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$$ ?

Comment: No! I think $\sin^2\arctan{x}=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$.

Comment: Delete please your "solution". I think it's not good, which you are doing.

Comment: If you don't like  the last part of my proof see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481332/inequality-for-three-variables).The answer of Piquito is very useful.

Comment: I think it's nothing.

Comment: Why does this have 2 upvotes? The original inequality can also be analyzed via computer, which the author obviously did already.

Comment: @MaximGilula   This solution is wrong. We can see it from two aspects.

1) Clearly, when $x = y = z = \sqrt{\frac{13}{5}}$, the inequality holds with equality.
However, the last inequality in this solution holds without equality for any $y > 0$.
The easy way to see this is to plot it in math software (surely, one can prove it rigorously).

Comment: 2) The minimum is not attained at 
$x = \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{77}}{17} - \frac{26}{17}}$. This is why something is wrong.

Comment: Actually, what he did is to transform the problem to $F(x, y, z) = g(x) + h(y, z) \ge 0$ with constraints $xyz = (\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}})^3$ and $x, y, z > 0$. Here, 
$g(x) = \sqrt{\tfrac{5}{13}}\frac{1}{13}\tfrac{(x)^3}{(x^2+1)} 
- \tfrac{1}{18}\sqrt{\tfrac{5}{13}}\, x$.

Comment: Yes, it seems "$x$" is separated. 
Then he minimized $g(x)$ at $x = \alpha = \sqrt{\frac{3\sqrt{77}}{17} - \frac{26}{17}}$
(this is not true). With $x = \alpha$, then 
he wanted to prove $g(\alpha ) + h(y, z) \ge 0$ with the constraints
$yz = (\sqrt{\frac{13}{5}})^3/\alpha = \beta$ and $y, z > 0$.
Finally, with $z = \frac{\beta}{y}$, he wanted to
prove $g(\alpha) + h(y, \frac{\beta}{y}) \ge 0$ with the constraint $y > 0$.
However, the mistake arises when he minimized $g(x)$.

Comment: @RiverLi I was saying 2 upvotes is 2 too many... Wrong or not. And now there are 4!

Comment: @MaximGilula  Yes, I just agree with you.

Comment: @RiverLi I see!

Answer (score 1):

### Partial Answer

Alex Ravsky prove the following [statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563335/prove-or-disprove-this-statement/3566767?noredirect=1#comment7350022_3566767) :

> > Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ and $a\geq b\geq c$ and $13a^2+5b^2\geq 13b^2+5c^2\geq 13c^2+5a^2$ then $\exists n>1$ such that :$$\frac{a^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13a^2+5b^2)}{54n}\geq \frac{13a^2+5b^2}{54}$$
> > $$\Big(\frac{a^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13a^2+5b^2)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{b^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13b^2+5c^2)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(13a^2+5b^2)(13b^2+5c^2)}{54^2}$$
> > $$\Big(\frac{a^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13a^2+5b^2)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{b^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13b^2+5c^2)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{c^3}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(13c^2+5a^2)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(13a^2+5b^2)(13b^2+5c^2)(13c^2+5a^2)}{54^3}$$

Or :

> > Let $a,b,c>0$ such that  $\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq \frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}\geq \frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}$ and $a\geq b\geq c$ and $13a^2+5b^2\geq 13b^2+5c^2\geq 13c^2+5a^2$  then  $\exists n>1$ such that :$$\frac{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{54}$$
> > $$\Big(\frac{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{54^2}$$
> > $$\Big(\frac{\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5c^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\Big(\frac{\frac{c^3}{13c^2+5a^2}}{n}+ \frac{(n-1)(a+b+c)}{54n}\Big)\geq \frac{(a+b+c)^3}{54^3}$$

Remains to apply Karamata's inequality to get the desired result .By Karamata's inequality I mean this special case :

> > If $a_1\geq a_2\geq a_3\geq\cdots\geq a_n$ and $b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq\cdots\geq b_n$  are two sequences of positive real  numbers then we have  $\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n}\geq \frac{a_2}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_2}{n} \geq\cdots\geq \frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_n}{n}$and $b_1\geq b_2\geq b_3\geq\cdots\geq b_n$  satisfying the following conditions(call the conditions $C$):$$\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n}\geq b_1,(\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n})(\frac{a_2}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_2}{n})\geq b_1b_2,\cdots,(\frac{a_1}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_1}{n})(\frac{a_2}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_2}{n})\cdots (\frac{a_n}{n}+\frac{(n-1)b_n}{n})\geq b_1b_2\cdots b_n,$$ Then we have :
> > $$a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n\geq b_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_n$$

Ps:If you look properly to the solution of Alex Ravsky we can invert $a$ and $b$ and get  another case.

---

---

The easy case as $a\geq b \geq c>0$ :

let $x\in[0,1]$ then define :

### $$h\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{9}\left(1+\left(\frac{3}{2+x}-1\right)\frac{\left(1+x\frac{4.5+\frac{4.75x}{2}\left(1-x\right)}{3}\right)}{3}\right)$$

Then we have $x\in[0,1]$:

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{13+5x^{2}}+\frac{1}{18}-h\left(x\right)\geq 0$$

Remains to show $a\geq b \geq c>0$:

$$\frac{c^{3}}{13c^{2}+5a^{2}}-\frac{2\left(a+b\right)+c}{18}+\left(ah\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)+bh\left(\frac{c}{b}\right)\right)\geq 0\tag{I}$$

Dividing by $a$ $(I)$ and plugging $X=\frac{b}{a}$ and $Y=\frac{c}{b}$ we have :

$$g(X,Y)=Xh(Y)+h(X)-(X+1)\cdot\frac{1}{9}-\frac{XY}{18}+XY\cdot\frac{1}{13+\frac{5}{\left(XY\right)^{2}}}$$

Using the fact that for $Y$ fixed we have :

Let $0<x\leq y\leq 1$ :

$$h(x)\geq h(y)$$

And for $0<x\leq y\leq 1$ and $\frac{1}{3}\leq a\leq 1$:

$$xh\left(a\right)-\left(\frac{x+1}{9}\right)-\frac{xa}{18}+\frac{xa}{18}\cdot\frac{1}{13+\frac{5}{\left(xa\right)^{2}}}\geq yh\left(a\right)-\left(\frac{y+1}{9}\right)-\frac{ya}{18}+\frac{ya}{18}\cdot\frac{1}{13+\frac{5}{\left(ya\right)^{2}}} $$

To show this two fact one can use the definition of a decreasing function .

The rest is smooth because now two variables on $a,b,c$ are equal .

For the hard case we have an interesting result with :

$$H(x)=\frac{2}{18}\left(1+\left(1+\frac{1.5x^{2}\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{\left(x+1\right)^{2}}\right)\left(\frac{3}{2+x}-1\right)\frac{\left(1+x\frac{4.5+\frac{4.75x}{2}\left(1-x\right)}{3}\right)}{3}\right)$$

To be continued ...

Third way :

It seems that the function for $u\geq k\geq p>0$ :

$$\frac{x}{13+5\left(\frac{p\left(x+u\right)}{x+k}\right)^{2}}=f(x)$$

is convex on $(0,\infty)$ so using the substitution :

$$b=a\left(a+u\right)\cdot\frac{p}{a+k},c=b\left(b+u\right)\cdot\frac{p}{b+k}$$

Remains to show :

$$2f\left(\frac{\left(a+b\right)}{2}\right)+\frac{c^{3}}{13c^{2}+5a^{2}}-\frac{a+b+c}{18}\geq 0$$

Wich seems true .

To be continued .

Edit 17/03/2022 :

Taking $d>0$ such that :

$$\frac{c^{3}}{13c^{2}+5a^{2}}=f\left(d\right)$$

And using the same strategy as above (where we use the convexity of $f(x)$ and Jensen's inequality :

We have to show :

$$3f\left(\frac{\left(a+b+d\right)}{3}\right)-\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)}{18}\geq 0$$

Remark : To lighten the cubic to a second degree polynomial we can use the substitution $d=ct$ and then use weighted Jensen's inequality .

Second remark :

We can introduce the function :
$$g\left(x\right)=\frac{c}{13+\frac{5a^{2}}{c^{2}}}-\frac{c}{13+\frac{5p^{2}\left(x+u\right)^{2}}{\left(x+k\right)^{2}}}$$

Now it's not a quadratic but we have to solve a one degree polynomial or $g(d)=0$. Where $d>0$

Unfortunetaly it adds some constraint .

In fact with the constraint above the inequality is proved for :

$$p\leq \frac{k+\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)}{1+1+\frac{c}{d}}}{u+\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)}{1+1+\frac{c}{d}}}$$

Last edit 18/03/2022:
In fact there is a contradiction with the last constraint with $p$ . It should be :
$$a=\left(\frac{bp\left(b+u\right)}{b+k}\right),b=c\left(\frac{c\left(c+u\right)}{c+k}\right)$$

And :

$$r\left(x\right)=\frac{a}{13+\frac{5c^{2}}{a^{2}}}-\frac{a}{13+\frac{5p^{2}\left(x+u\right)^{2}}{\left(x+k\right)^{2}}}$$

$$\frac{\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)}{2+\frac{a}{d}}+k}{\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)}{2+\frac{a}{d}}+u}\geq p$$

---

---

---

---

---

Comment: No, because your inequality is obviously wrong.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I have checked my inequality is the same as yours and if you say that is wrong we got a contradiction in Math.

Comment: @RiverLi what do you think about all of this ?

Comment: @The.old.boy   Since I did not comment here before, even you @ me, I did not know. I just looked at this post and see your comment. I do not know if your approach is correct. As I pointed out before, you only prove one of several cases. If you write the full solution for all cases, I may review it.

Comment: @The.old.boy   If so, you should add explanation about it.

Comment: Following comment : I forget to say $a\geq 1$

Comment: Let $$h\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2+x^{-2}}+\frac{1}{18}+\frac{x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}}{5}\right)-\frac{1}{13+5x^{-2}}-\frac{1}{18\cdot6}\leq 0$$ for $x$ in $[0,1]$

Comment: We can improve it in fact we have : $$h\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2+x^{-2}}\right)+\frac{x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}}{30}\right)\left(1+\frac{x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}}{22.5}\right)^{4}-\left(\frac{1}{13+5x^{-2}}\right)\le 0$$ for x in$[0,1]$

Comment: In fact if allowed to $d<0$ such that $f(x)$ is also convex on $[d,\infty)$ it works partially under some assumptions on $p,u,k$ using Fuchs inequality wich extends Karamata's inequality .

Answer (score 1):

I am not a reputable source, but I think I can prove the following theorem: $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}+k_{2}}$$

**PROOF**

We will need firstly the following

**Lemma 1.**

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{\alpha+1}\geq\sum_{cyc}a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}$$

**Proof.**

Applying the Rearrangement inequality on $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ and $a_{1}^{\alpha},a_{2}^{\alpha},...,a_{n}^{\alpha}$, we have that $\sum_{cyc}a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}$ is maximized when $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ and $a_{1}^{\alpha},a_{2}^{\alpha},...,a_{n}^{\alpha}$ are similarly sorted.

Therefore, we can affirm that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{\alpha+1}\geq\sum_{cyc}a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}$$

Other hand, we need the following

**Lemma 2.**

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}+\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}}$$

**Proof.**

We establish that

$$\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}+\frac{n}{m}=\frac{a_{1}}{k_{1}}$$

Operating, we get that

$$\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}m+n\left(k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}\right)}{m\left(k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}\right)}=\frac{a_{1}}{k_{1}}$$

$$k_{1}\left(a_{1}^{\alpha+1}m+n\left(k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}\right)\right)=a_{1}m\left(k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}\right)$$

$$k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha+1}m+k_{1}n\left(k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}\right)=a_{1}mk_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+a_{1}mk_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}$$

$$k_{1}n\left(k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}\right)=a_{1}mk_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}$$

$$\frac{n}{m}=\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)\frac{a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}$$

Therefore, we have that

$$\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}+\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}=\frac{a_{1}}{k_{1}}$$

And subsequently, repeating the process for each variable, we get that

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}+\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}}$$

Now, we are ready to prove the theorem.

Applying Lemma 1, we derive that

$$\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{\alpha+1}\geq\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)\sum_{cyc}a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}$$

Therefore, substituting in the expression of Lemma 2 and operating, we have that

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}+\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{k}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}}$$

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\left(\frac{k_{1}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{1}^{\alpha+1}+\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{k}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}}$$

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{\left(\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{k}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}}$$

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{k}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{\left(\frac{k_{1}+k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)k_{1}}$$

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{k}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}}{k_{1}+k_{2}}$$

As we wanted to prove.

The particular case proposed follows from the direct application of the theorem.

Comment: The first lemma is wrong because the right hand side is cyclic so you can't order the variables without losing generality.

Comment: You are right @Atticus! Do you think there could be some way to prove that $\sum_{cyc}a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}$ is maximum when all the variables are well ordered? That would fix the Lemma.

Comment: Maybe the Lemma could be proved using the Rearrangement inequality? In any case, for three variables, using the Rearrangement inequality it would be possible to prove that $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$, and then the theorem would hold for cyclic sums of this type with three variables

Comment: Lemma 1 is provable for $n$ variables, however there are mistakes further down the line (some circular reason). I suggest you write the proof for the three variable version, it will be easier to pinpoint them.

Comment: @Atticus, I think I found the circular reason you mentioned... I have tried to fix it, as well as the proof of Lemma 1. Do you think that now is ok? Thanks for your review and help!

Comment: The proof of Lemma 1 is ok. The generalized inequality you try to prove however is not true. For example $$\frac{a^8}{a^7+b^7}+\frac{b^8}{b^7+c^7}+\frac{c^8}{c^7+a^7}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{2}$$ does not hold for $(a,b,c)=(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{5})$. Because of how you chose to write your proof, it's hard (for me) to pinpoint where exactly you went wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @LHF, I think I found the error... the theorem is only valid for variables greater than one, as $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a_{1}^{\alpha+1}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{\left(\frac{k_{2}}{k_{1}}\right)a_{1}a_{2}^{\alpha}}{k_{1}a_{1}^{\alpha}+k_{2}a_{2}^{\alpha}}$$ is not necesarily true for variables less than one. For variables greater than one, the theorem holds.

Answer (score -1):

Let $f,g,p,u,k,d,x,y,z>0$ such that $u\geq k$:

$$y=\left(\frac{x\left(g+u\right)p}{g+k}\right),x=\left(\frac{z\left(d+u\right)p}{d+k}\right),z=\left(\frac{y\left(f+u\right)p}{f+k}\right)$$

Then we have the functions :

$$h\left(x\right)=\frac{x}{13+\frac{5p^{2}\left(x+u\right)^{2}}{\left(x+k\right)^{2}}}$$

Wich is convex on $(0,\infty)$ and $u\ge k>0$ and $p> 0$  :

Then using Jensen's inequality we have :

$$\frac{z}{f}h(f)+\frac{x}{d}h(d)+\frac{y}{g}h(g)\geq \left(\frac{z}{f}+\frac{x}{d}+\frac{y}{g}\right)h\left(\frac{\left(z+x+y\right)}{\frac{z}{f}+\frac{x}{d}+\frac{y}{g}}\right)$$

Now the problem is :

$$\left(\frac{z}{f}+\frac{x}{d}+\frac{y}{g}\right)h\left(\frac{\left(z+x+y\right)}{\frac{z}{f}+\frac{x}{d}+\frac{y}{g}}\right)\geq^{?}\frac{\left(x+y+z\right)}{18}\tag{I}$$

After simplification we have the constraint :

$$p(\frac{\left(z+x+y\right)}{\frac{z}{f}+\frac{x}{d}+\frac{y}{g}}+u)\leq \frac{\left(z+x+y\right)}{\frac{z}{f}+\frac{x}{d}+\frac{y}{g}}+k$$

we are done .

Last edit 23/04/2022 :

We have the inequality for $x\in[0,1]$ :

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{1}{13+5x^{-2}}\right)\geq g(x)=\left(\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2+x^{-2}}+\frac{x^{2}\left(1-x\right)^{2}}{5}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{\left(x\left(1-x\right)\right)^{2}}{16.75}\right)^{3}$$

Now we need to show under some assumptions given below:

$$p(a,b,c)=-\frac{\left(a+b+c\right)}{18}+ag\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+bf\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)+\frac{c^{3}}{13c^{2}+5a^{2}}\geq 0$$

For that we use Buffalo's way and a constraint we have all the coefficient positives in ($x\ge 0$ and $n\geq 1$ a natural number) :

$$p(0.785,1.25+x,1.861+x^n)$$

Comment: @RiverLi I think we can gnenralize my partial proof are you agree ?

Comment: Before discussing new inequalities, please give a step-by-step proof for the general $n$ in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351612/prove-that-displaystyle-prod-k-1n-frac1x-kx-k-geq-prod-k-1n-fr/4399286#4399286. Or say something like: I don't have a proof for general $n$. I only have a proof for $n=3$. It is important to make sure you indeed have a complete proof.

Comment: We can generalize the last result with $p(0.785,1.25+x^m,1.861+x^n)$ where $n\geq m\geq 1$are natural numbers  and $m$ divides $n$.

Answer (score -1):

Here, I present the computer-generated Buffalo Way solution.

We want to prove $$325 x^{5}y^{2} + 125 x^{5}z^{2} + 325 x^{4}y^{3} - 845 x^{4}y^{2}z - 325 x^{4}yz^{2} - 325 x^{4}z^{3} - 325 x^{3}y^{4} + 720 x^{3}y^{2}z^{2} + 325 x^{3}z^{4} + 125 x^{2}y^{5} - 325 x^{2}y^{4}z + 720 x^{2}y^{3}z^{2} + 720 x^{2}y^{2}z^{3} - 845 x^{2}yz^{4} + 325 x^{2}z^{5} - 845 xy^{4}z^{2} - 325 xy^{2}z^{4} + 325 y^{5}z^{2} + 325 y^{4}z^{3} - 325 y^{3}z^{4} + 125 y^{2}z^{5}$$ is positive.

This polynomial is cyclic.

Let $x = \min\{x, y, z\}$, $y = x + a$, $z = x + b$.

Substitution gives $$\left(360 a^{2} - 360 a b + 360 b^{2}\right) x^{5} + \left(540 a^{3} + 2760 a^{2} b - 2580 a b^{2} + 540 b^{3}\right) x^{4} + \left(1080 a^{4} + 2480 a^{3} b + 2520 a^{2} b^{2} - 4640 a b^{3} + 1080 b^{4}\right) x^{3} + \left(450 a^{5} + 2210 a^{4} b + 2540 a^{3} b^{2} - 1280 a^{2} b^{3} - 1220 a b^{4} + 450 b^{5}\right) x^{2} + \left(650 a^{5} b + 1755 a^{4} b^{2} - 675 a^{2} b^{4} + 250 a b^{5}\right) x + 325 a^{5} b^{2} + 325 a^{4} b^{3} - 325 a^{3} b^{4} + 125 a^{2} b^{5}$$

If we let $X = \frac{x}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}},$

For ${a}/{b}$ in range $\left[0.0, 0.45\right]$, the polynomial is larger than

$$\left(601 X^{5} - 64 X^{4} - 1175 X^{3} - 225 X^{2} + 655 X + 245\right)\left(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\right)^{7}$$

, which is positive.

For ${a}/{b}$ in range $\left[0.45, 0.5\right]$, the polynomial is larger than

$$\left(540 X^{5} - 43 X^{4} - 1124 X^{3} - 205 X^{2} + 655 X + 238\right)\left(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\right)^{7}$$

, which is positive.

For ${a}/{b}$ in range $\left[0.5, \infty\right)$, the polynomial is larger than

$$\left(360 X^{5} + 21 X^{4} - 930 X^{3} - 59 X^{2} + 690 X + 238\right)\left(\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\right)^{7}$$

, which is positive.

Therefore, we conclude the polynomial in question is positive.

Answer (score -4):

I have finally found a solution . In fact we start to study the 2 variables version of this inequality we have :

> $$\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}+\frac{b^3}{13b^2+5a^2}\geq \frac{a+b}{18}$$

Proof:

We have with $x=\frac{a}{b}$ :
$$\frac{x^3}{13x^2+5}+\frac{1}{13+5x^2}\geq \frac{1+x}{18}$$
Or 
$$5(x+1)(x-1)^2(5x^2-8x+5)\geq 0$$

So we have (if we permute the variables $a,b,c$ and addition the three inequalities ) :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5c^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{9}$$

If we have $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5c^2}$

We have :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$$
But also
$$\frac{(a-\epsilon)^3}{13(a-\epsilon)^2+5b^2}+\frac{(b)^3}{13(b)^2+5(c+\epsilon)^2}+\frac{(c+\epsilon)^3}{13(c+\epsilon)^2+5(a-\epsilon)^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$$
If we put $a\geq c $ and $\epsilon=a-c$

We finally obtain :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5c^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$$

So all the cases are here so it's proved !

Comment: If you'll say that it's proved it's not says that it's indeed proved. Stop please to post a wrong solutions.

Comment: Now it's right and proved .

Comment: I can only see that you proved that, for a given triple $(a, b, c)$,  $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$ **or** $\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5c^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$ must hold. – The same applies to your other answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3041504/42969.