# Inequality $\sum_{cyc}a^3\frac{(16a^2-10ab+12b^2)}{(13a^2+5b^2)^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

It's a variant of [Inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{13a^2+5b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{18}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777075/inequality-sum-limits-cyc-fraca313a25b2-geq-fracabc18) :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ then we have :
>   $$\sum_{cyc}a^3\frac{(16a^2-10ab+12b^2)}{(13a^2+5b^2)^2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{18}$$

My proof

Rewriting the inequality we have :
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+b+c}\frac{(16-10\frac{b}{a}+12(\frac{b}{a})^2)}{(13+5(\frac{b}{a})^2)^2}\geq \frac{1}{18}$$

Since the function $f(x)=\frac{16-10x+12x^2}{(13+5x^2)^2}$ is convex on $[0.02,+\infty[$ we can apply Jensen's inequality we get :

$$\frac{a}{a+b+c}f(\frac{b}{a})+\frac{b}{a+b+c}f(\frac{c}{b})+\frac{c}{a+b+c}f(\frac{a}{c})\geq f\Big(\frac{a\frac{b}{a}+b\frac{c}{b}+c\frac{a}{c}}{a+b+c}\Big)=\frac{1}{18}$$

So we prove the inequality for $\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{b},\frac{a}{c}\in[0.02,+\infty]$

The rest is smooth.

My question have you an alternative proof ?

Ps: I will (i have not the time today) make an update with strong convexity .

Comment: Your previous inequality was much more interesting

Comment: Yes I know but the function corresponding to my previous inequality was not convex so I change to give a proof .But I have a question  Do you think that with strong convexity we can prove your original inequality ? I know you doesn't accept this in a maths competition but your original inequality is too hard for tools like Am-Gm , C-S and so on ...

Comment: I think convexity does not helps here. At least I don't see, how it can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3(16a^2-10ab+12b^2)}{(13a^2+5b^2)^2}-\frac{a+b+c}{18}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^3(16a^2-10ab+12b^2)}{(13a^2+5b^2)^2}-\frac{a}{18}-\frac{a-b}{54}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(188a^3+5a^2b-50ab^2+25b^3)}{54(13a^2+5b^2)^2}\geq0$$
because by AM-GM:
$$188a^3+5a^2b-50ab^2+25b^3=188a^3+5a^2b+3\cdot\frac{25b^3}{3}-50ab^2\geq$$
$$\geq\left(5\sqrt[5]{188\cdot5\cdot\left(\frac{25}{3}\right)^3}-50\right)ab^2\geq0.$$

Comment: Always nice ! Thanks a lot .

Comment: @The.old.crap You are welcome! Your previous inequality is much more interesting. For the proof we need to use something else.