# An inequality derived from an olympiad one

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, examples-counterexamples

This problem is a kind of complement of [this](http://Olympiad%20Inequality%20%E2%88%91cycx48x3+5y3%E2%A9%BEx+y+z13).

Let $a,b,x,y,z\gt 0$, prove

$$\frac{x+y+z}{a+b}\ge \frac{xy^3}{ax^3+by^3}+\frac{yz^3}{ay^3+bz^3}+\frac{zx^3}{az^3+bx^3}$$

I have verified that this inequality is valid by computer and a lot of particular $(a, b, x, y, z)$ but I could not yet find a non-sophisticated proof.

Comment: The numerator of the last term should be $zx^3$? And the link in your question doesn’t work.

Comment: Thank you very much. The link is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775572/olympiad-inequality-sum-limits-cyc-fracx48x35y3-geqslant-fracxy/2424065?noredirect=1#comment6439072_2424065

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's wrong.

Try $(a,b,x,y,z)=(2,1,3,1,2).$

But it seems that it's true for $0< a\leq b$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your counter example

Comment: @Piquito You are welcome! I proved your inequality for $a=b=1$, but  I think there is a hard inequality for $a>b$, which still is true.

Comment: @Michel Rozenberg: It is valid for $(a,b)=(8,5)$ and in fact you do have $$A\ge\frac{x+y+z}{13}\ge B$$ where $A$ is the LHS in the link and $B$ is the RHS here. (I have written this problem is derived from the link).

Comment: @Piquito Yes, of course! I see it.