# Inequality Confusion, please guide me.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

**Question:**

We need to prove the following inequality :-

> $$\displaystyle \sum_{cyclic} \frac{x^4}{8x^3 + 5y^3} \geq \frac{x+y+z}{13} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+ $$

As we know by **AM-GM** that,

$$\displaystyle  \frac{x+y+z}{13} \geq \frac{3(xyz)^\frac{1}{3} }{13} $$  Can we say it is similar to prove  this

$$\displaystyle    \sum_{cyclic} \frac{x^4}{8x^3 + 5y^3} \geq \frac{3(xyz)^\frac{1}{3} }{13}$$

instead of the original equation.

Because then,

**SOLUTION**

$\displaystyle \sum_{cyclic} \frac{x^4}{8x^3 + 5y^3} \geq \frac{x+y+z}{13}  \geq \frac{3(xyz)^\frac{1}{3} }{13}$

So We can say  $$\displaystyle \   \     \   \sum_{cyclic} \frac{x^4}{8x^3 + 5y^3} \times 13(x^3 + y^3 +z^3)   \geq  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2  \  \   \       \  $$

By **Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality**  more precisely **Titu's Lemma**

Also we can see that $\displaystyle  \          \  (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2  \geq 9(xyz)^\frac{4}{3} $

This will result in

> $$\displaystyle \sum_{cyclic} (\frac{x^4}{8x^3 + 5y^3}) \times (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) \geq 3(xyz) \frac{3(xyz)^\frac{1}{3} }{13}$$

Now we can tell $\displaystyle  {(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)} \geq {3(xyz)} \ \ \ $ (always true) i.e it is equivalent to say that $\displaystyle \sum_{cyclic} (\frac{x^4}{8x^3 + 5y^3}) \geq \frac{3(xyz)^\frac{1}{3} }{13} .$

Am I correct ?

Comment: If you find a lower bound to the RHS and prove that LHS is greater than that bound, it  does not mean that LHS is greater than RHS.

Comment: Ok, Some other way to do this ?

Comment: And why is it that ?

Comment: the thing you mentioned as similar to prove is not correct. AM>=GM but if you prove x^4/(8x^3 + 5y^3) >= GM then it might even be that AM >= x^4/(8x^3 + 5y^3). AM can be even more.

Comment: Because if 4>3 and 5>3, it doesn't mean 4>5.

Comment: @user693540 Please clearify the reason ...

Comment: @Atticus Ok, I got your point. That was my confusion.

Comment: Can you please suggest some other way ?

Comment: If you're just learning inequalities, I suggest to put this inequality aside for some time. I think it's very hard.

Comment: No, I am quite handy with them...

Comment: The only thing is I am not able to relate with the problem. I am confused which inequality to use.

Comment: I am aware about Jesen's Inequality, Holder's inequality, Muirhead's Inequality,Chebyshev's Inequality..

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi, The problem is I highly doubt any classical inequality works for this question. It would probably need some brute-force way with computer software. What is the source?

Comment: Ok, do you know something about it ?

Comment: [Source]                                                                                                            
  : https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/olympiad-inequality/

Comment: There's a refference in your link to the following question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775572/olympiad-inequality-sum-limits-cyc-fracx48x35y3-geqslant-fracxy. That pretty much clears it up what a hard question this is.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi If you know that $A\geq C$ and $B\geq C$ then you still don't know  if $A\geq B$ is true so this is why your approach doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for guiding.