# Prove $\sum \sqrt{3a+\frac{1}{b}} \geq 6$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cyclic-decomposition

For $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$. Prove that$:$
$$\sqrt{3a+\frac{1}{b}} +\sqrt{3b+\frac{1}{c}} +\sqrt{3c+\frac{1}{a}} \geqq 6$$

My work$:$

This inequality equivalent to$:$

$$3(a+b+c) +\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} +2\sum \sqrt{(3a+\frac{1}{b})(3b+\frac{1}{c})}\geqq 36$$

Or $$ \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} +2\sum \sqrt{(3a+\frac{1}{b})(3b+\frac{1}{c})} \geqq 27$$

By C-S$,$ $$\sqrt{(2a+a+\frac{1}{b})(2b+\frac{1}{c}+b)} \geqq (2\sqrt{ab} +\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}+1)$$

Hence$,$ it is enough to prove: 
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} +2 \sum (2\sqrt{ab} +\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}) \geqq 21$$

But by AM-GM$,$ $$\frac{1}{a} +\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} +\sum \sqrt{ab} \geqq 3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{abc}} +3\sqrt[3]{abc} \geqq 6$$

So we need to prove$:$ $$3 \sum \sqrt{ab} +2\sum \sqrt{\frac{a}{c}} \geqq 15$$

But I don't know what I need to do next$?$

Comment: Your final inequality is not true. Try $(1.5,1,0.5)$.

Comment: @CulverKwan Thank you!

Comment: @MartinR but it's ugly so I want another?

Comment: @tthnew Perhaps the solution presented isn't pretty; part of the real world is being able to read someone else's work, develop your own ideas, and synthesize the answer to fit your own needs.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589716

Comment: @tthnew We can also use Holder and BW. I just gave a solution in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475842/a-cyclic-inequality-sum-limits-cyc-sqrt3x-frac1y-geqslant-6